Showing analytically that sampling exactly 1 period of a sinusoid yields a spectrum with no lobes in the DFT
The DTFT of a discrete sinusoid $f[k] = \sin(\omega_0 k)$ is
$$F(\Omega)=i\pi(\delta[\Omega-\omega_0] + \delta[\Omega+\omega_0]), \: \: \:  \Omega \in [-\pi, \pi)$$
The DTFT of a rect function $w[k] = \text{rect}_M[k] = \begin{cases} 1 \: \: \: 0 \leq k \leq M \\\\ 0 \: \: \: \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ is
$$W(\Omega) = e^{-j\Omega M/2} \frac{\sin(\frac{M+1}{2}\Omega)}{\sin(\frac{1}{2}\Omega)} $$
A discrete sinusoid that lasts exactly one period $N_0 = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$ can be expressed as
$$y[k] = f[k]\text{rect}_{N_0}[k] $$
When we multiply in time we convolve in frequency, so
$$Y(\Omega) = F(\Omega) \ast W(\Omega) $$
Convolving with an impulse yields a replica of the function at the impulse's location
$$Y(\Omega) = W(\Omega-\omega_0) + W(\Omega+\omega_0) $$
$$Y(\Omega) = e^{-j(\Omega-\omega_0) M/2} \frac{\sin(\frac{M+1}{2}(\Omega-\omega_0))}{\sin(\frac{1}{2}(\Omega-\omega_0))} + 
e^{-j(\Omega+\omega_0) M/2} \frac{\sin(\frac{M+1}{2}(\Omega+\omega_0))}{\sin(\frac{1}{2}(\Omega+\omega_0))} \tag1$$
Here is where I'm stuck. I wish to find the zero-crossings of $(1)$. The location of those zero-crossings should hopefully be at $\Omega = r\Omega_0, r\in \mathbb{Z}$ with the exception of two points at $\Omega = \omega_0$ and $\Omega = -\omega_0$. Is it possible to complete the demonstration analytically?

Sorry, your very first equation is wrong. The DTFT of a sine wave is periodic delta and there is a  complex scale factor  missing. Also eq(1) is wrong. The magnitude of the sums is NOT equal to the sum of the individual magnitudes. You can't just disregard out the phase terms.

@Hilmar You are right. I will ammend.

I'm not gonna do an answer (too lazy), but sampling exactly one period of a sinusoid (or any periodic function) and applying the DTFT is precisely what the DFT is.

I know you already accepted an answer, but see this answer and the linked answer in the post I made https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/94745/fft-amplitude-and-fft-bin-averaging/94747#94747 . Essentially, the DFT basis is composed of all possible discrete complex exponentials that are periodic in $N$ samples. The inner product of one with itself is 1, and zero for inner products with all other basis functions. If a sinusoid is perfectly periodic, it is composed of two DFT basis functions and will produce a spectrum with no leakage.

To solve the roots, set:
$$e^{-j(\Omega-\omega_o)M/2}\frac{\sin \bigg(\frac{M+1}{2} (\Omega - \omega_o))\bigg)}{\sin((\Omega-\omega_0)/2)} = -e^{-j(\Omega+\omega_o)M/2}\frac{\sin \bigg(\frac{M+1}{2} (\Omega + \omega_o))\bigg)}{\sin((\Omega+\omega_0)/2)}$$
When the above equality holds the result will be zero. First starting with a substitution to make this manageable:
Using:
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(\Omega-\omega_o)$$
$$\beta = \frac{1}{2}(\Omega+\omega_o)$$
We get the following equality to find the zeros:
$$e^{-jM\alpha}\frac{\sin(\alpha(M+1))}{\sin(\alpha)} = - e^{-jM\beta}\frac{\sin(\beta(M+1))}{\sin(\beta)}$$
By substituting $\beta = \alpha + \omega_o$ we can factor out a $e^{-jM\alpha}$ term:
$$e^{-jM\alpha}\frac{\sin(\alpha(M+1))}{\sin(\alpha)} =  - e^{-jM\alpha}e^{-jM\omega_o}\frac{\sin((\alpha+\omega_o)(M+1))}{\sin(\alpha + \omega_o)}$$
Resulting in:
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha(M+1))}{\sin(\alpha)} =  -e^{-jM\omega_o}\frac{\sin((\alpha+\omega_o)(M+1))}{\sin(\alpha + \omega_o)} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
The left side is completely real, so the equality can only occur when the right side is real or when both sides are zero. In order for the right side to be real, we must have  $M\omega_o = n_1 \pi$ with $n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $-e^{-jM\omega_o} = \pm 1$. This covers the solution for all cases where both sides are not zero.
As for when both sides are zero, the right side is zero when $(\alpha+\omega_o)(M+1)) = n \pi, \space n \in \mathbb{Z}$
Similarly, the left side is zero when $\alpha(M+1)) + \omega_o=n\pi, \space n \in \mathbb{Z}$
Equating the two, we get $(\alpha+\omega_o) = \alpha$, with the only solution then being $\omega_0 = 0$
Therefore the only solutions for $\omega_0 \ne 0$ can be when $M\omega_o = n_1 \pi$ with $n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$
Within this constraint, we seek a relationship for $\Omega$ for finding the roots:
Given that $M\omega_o = n_1 \pi$ , and substituting that into equation \ref{1}:
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha(n_1\pi/\omega_o+1))}{\sin(\alpha)} =  \frac{\sin(\alpha(n_1\pi/\omega_o+1) + n_1\pi + \omega_o)}{\sin(\alpha + \omega_o)}, \space\space\space\text{ for } n_1\text{: even integers}$$
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha(n_1\pi/\omega_o+1))}{\sin(\alpha)} =  -\frac{\sin(\alpha(n_1\pi/\omega_o+1) + n_1\pi + \omega_o)}{\sin(\alpha + \omega_o)}, \space\space\space\text{ for } n_1 \text{: odd integers}$$
Conveniently, $\sin(\theta+n\pi) = \pm \sin(\theta)$ so with that we remove the even/odd dependence and have no alternating sign:
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha(n_1\pi/\omega_o+1))}{\sin(\alpha)} =   \frac{\sin(\alpha(n_1\pi/\omega_o+1) + \omega_o)}{\sin(\alpha + \omega_o)}, \space n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}, \space \omega_0 = n_1\pi/M$$
Substituting out $\omega_0$ we get:
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha(M+1))}{\sin(\alpha)} =  \frac{\sin(\alpha(M+1) + n_1\pi/M)}{\sin(\alpha +n_1\pi/M)}  \space n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}, \space M \in \mathbb{Z}>0 \tag{2}\label{2}$$
If we use $M = n_1\pi/\alpha$, the above simplifies to a clear equality where both sides of the equation evaluate to $1$ as follows:
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha(\frac{n_1\pi}{\alpha}+1))}{\sin(\alpha)} =  \pm \frac{\sin(\alpha(\frac{n_1\pi}{\alpha}+1) + \alpha)}{\sin(\alpha +\alpha)}$$
leading to
$$\frac{\sin(n_1\pi + \alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)} =   \frac{\sin(n_1\pi +2\alpha)}{\sin(2\alpha)}$$
Since $\sin(\theta+n_1\pi)=\pm \sin(\theta)$, both sides are equal to $\pm 1$ for all $n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$
Therefore the following is a valid solution for the zeros:
$$\alpha = \frac{n_1\pi}{M}, \space \space n_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Substituting $\alpha$ back in we get:
$$(\Omega - \omega_o) = \frac{2\pi n_1}{M}, \space \text{with }\omega_o=\frac{n_2\pi}{M}, \space n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z},\text{ and }  n_1 \ne n_2/2 $$
Resulting in:
$$\Omega = \frac{2\pi n_1}{M} + \frac{n_2\pi}{M}, \space n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}, n_2 = (M\omega_0)/\pi, M \in \mathbb{Z}>0 \text{ and }  n_1 \ne n_2/2 $$
Since $\space n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, the following relationship is also valid:
$$\Omega = \frac{2\pi n}{M}, n \in \mathbb{Z},\text{ with } \omega_o = n_2\pi/M \text{ for integer } n_2 \text{ and } \Omega \ne \pm \omega_o $$

Note the Dirichlet Kernel as orginally used by the OP typically has an additional scaling factor and is given as follows (but that doesn't change the result):
$$\bigg|D(\omega)\bigg| = \bigg|\frac{\sin(N\omega/2)}{N\sin(\omega/2)}\bigg|$$

Brilliant Dan! You got it nailed down in the end. Kudos is in order.

@Carl ok done, that wasn't as easy as I first thought.

Hey Dan, can you elaborate on why we can set $M=\frac{n_1 \pi}{\alpha}$ after equation (2)? It is not obvious to me why that substitution is valid.

@Carl - Hi Carl- I recognized that it allowed us to pull out the $n\pi$ term and the idea was to test if it was even a solution. It's not a substitution but a test of one possible solution that was then proven to be valid.
